# Getting a non-selected radio buttons from request in servlet Java

Tags: java, servlets, request, radio-button

It may seem strange, but I need to get values of non-selected radio buttons for each radio button's group. I have used the code below to get all the selected buttons values, but I need to get the unselected ones.

```
        ArrayList <String> userSelection = new ArrayList <String>();
        Enumeration names = request.getParameterNames();
        String selection = "";
        while ( names.hasMoreElements() )
        {
           name = (String) names.nextElement();
           userSelection.add(request.getParameter( selection ));
        }
```

Comment: You already know all radiobuttons beforehand in the server side code. How else could you display all radiobuttons? :) Just do `allradiobuttons - selectedradiobuttons = unselectedradiobuttons`.

Comment: :) I know but buttons names are stored in a hash sets which are stored in array (each element in array is a group of buttons), and I though I could avoid iterating over the array.

Comment: Store values in a `List` and use `List#retainAll()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser will not send you the non-selected buttons.  What you'll need to do is either:

1. Have your code know what all the buttons will be
2. Create a hidden field with a list of all the possible values.

If you go with #2, take heed of Mr HEBERT'S suggestion to never trust user input.

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't get those values form your request.

It's the browser which will create the request and it doesn't send informations that appears useless for the navigation (such as unused values).

The only way to do that would be to guess the values.

Remember this request could be forged by hand so, never trust user input.